# R: Update column based on matching rows from another data frame

Tags: r, merge, match

I have

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), color = c("red", NA, NA, NA, "green"), name = c("tom", "dick", "harry", "steve", "mike"))
mydf2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,99), color = c("red", "orange", "yellow"), name = c("tom", "dick", "Aaron"))
```

I would like to update mydf1$color with the corresponding color from mydf2 for any rows that match on both ID and name. The desired output would be to update the color in row 2 to orange and leave the rest as is:

```
   ID  color   name
1  1   red     tom
2  2   orange  dick
3  3   <NA>    harry
4  4   <NA>    steve
5  5   green   mike
```

I tried solutions with asymmetric merging as in some previous posts, but obtained undesired overwriting of some of my fields in mydf1. I then tried using match as suggested in another post but received an error. Not sure why the match condition is not working.

```
mydf1$color <- mydf2$color[match(mydf1[c("ID", "name")], mydf2[c("ID", "name")])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a join with `data.table` `on` the 'ID' and 'name' column and update the corresponding value of 'color' from the second dataset in the first dataset by assignment (`:=`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf1)[mydf2, color := i.color, on = .(ID, name)]
mydf1
#   ID  color  name
#1:  1    red   tom
#2:  2 orange  dick
#3:  3   <NA> harry
#4:  4   <NA> steve
#5:  5  green  mike
```

---

`match` works on `vector/matrix` and not on `data.frame`.  If we need to use `match`, then `paste` the 'ID', 'name' from each datasets and do a `match`

```
i1 <- match(paste(mydf1$ID, mydf1$name), paste(mydf2$ID, mydf2$name), nomatch = 0)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf1 %>%
   left_join(mydf2, by = c("ID", "name")) %>%
    transmute(ID, name, color = coalesce(as.character(color.x), 
                                         as.character(color.y)))
#  ID  name  color
#1  1   tom    red
#2  2  dick orange
#3  3 harry   <NA>
#4  4 steve   <NA>
#5  5  mike  green
```

Comment: Looks like it works though the syntax is a bit opaque to me. Is there a base or tidy verse solution to this problem?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the base solution using match yet. Results in error "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "color", value = 1:2) :  replacement has 2 rows, data has 5". The dplyr method works perfectly when the field to be replaced is "NA". Is there any way to adapt so that any value present in df1$color is replaced by the corresponding value in df2 for matching rows?

Comment: @marcel base R. solution is to use the `i1` on both datasets if you are using `match`.  However, it is more easier if you do with `merge` i.e. `merge(mydf1, mydf2, by = c("ID", "name"))` andd then replace the values in 'color.x an d'color.y as showed iin the tidyverse

Comment: I finally came up with the following, for the situation where color in mydf1 has an entry other than NA, but needs to be updated by the matching entry in mydf2;  mydf1 %>%
  mutate_if(.predicate = is.factor, .funs = as.character) %>%
  left_join(mydf2, by = c("ID", "name")) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(is.na(color.y) ~ color.x, !is.na(color.y) ~ color.y)) %>%
  select(-color.x, -color.y)

Answer (score 1):

As of `dplyr` version 1.0, you can use the experimental `rows_*` functions. Unfortunately `rows_update` doesn't allow for a "inner" or "left" update--it will throw an error if there are non-matching rows. We can work around this using `rows_upsert` followed by a `inner_join`:

```
rows_upsert(mydf1, mydf2, by = c("ID", "name")) %>%
  inner_join(mydf1 %>% select(ID, name))
# Joining, by = c("ID", "name")
#   ID  color  name
# 1  1    red   tom
# 2  2 orange  dick
# 3  3   <NA> harry
# 4  4   <NA> steve
# 5  5  green  mike
```